# How do I use SharePoint Rest API to query list for a field resulting in one row of data?

Tags: 2013, rest, filter

I've been able to pull data for a specific list, but unable to filter it down to one item, where the Field called "File Name" equals drugdealers. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
url: "https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/items(1)/?$filter=File_x0020_Name Eq drugdealers",
type: "GET",
headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
cache:false,                
success: function(data){
console.log(data);
var items = [];
$(data.d.results).each(function(){
items.push('<ul id="' + 'listUL' + '">' + 
'<li id="' + 'listLI' + '">' + 
this.Title  +
'</li>' + 
'</ul>');
});
items.push("</div>");
$("#listResult").html(items.join(''))}
});
</script>

<div id="listResult"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drop the (1) in the url. You are querying just item number 1. 
If you want to limit to 1 item use top.

url: "https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/items?$filter=File_x0020_Name Eq 'FDAAgents'&$top=1"

Watch your results though. returning 1 item comes back differently than returning a set of items containing 1 item. (I use DHC chrome app to make sure I am getting back what I expect to be getting before developing on it. Lots of folks including MS support use fiddler)

Comment: That did it, big thanks for all the help. Let me know if I need to make a separate post for my next question. I'd be happy to do so.

I was able to test and pull data. Now, how in the world do I format the date returns and spaces. Currently, it just joins all the data into one long string of all my columns that meet the one query for page1.

How do I format it to something like this:
Title:  Regions
Module: FDAAgents
Comments: This course is for you.

Comment: Throwing that into another separate question provides more community benefit if you don't mind.

Comment: google fp142385

Answer (score 0):

Change the URL as below

```
url: "https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/items(1)/?$filter=File_x0020_Name Eq 'drugdealers'"
```